# como actualizar ruta de las imagenes de una pagina hecha en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, imagen, url

tengo una pagina hecha en wordpress y la cambie de directorio con un dominio nuevo, movi todos los archivos y modifique las rutas de las imagenes en la base de datos en la tabla options y los datos de conexion a la base de datos pero me siguen apreciendo los enlaces de imagenes rotos, si hago click derecho y y luego en ver imagen en la URL me sigue colocando el subdominio anterior luego del nuevo subdominio, es decir, esta referenciando al dominio anterior y por eso no encuentra la imagen, que mas podria hacer, xq ya modifique las rutas de las imagenes en la base de datos y es como si no lo hubiera hecho porque sigue con el mismo problema, ya limpie cache y nada, alguna solucion?

Comment: Esta herramienta puede serte util: https://rudrastyh.com/tools/sql-queries-generator

Comment: amigo @FranciscoGarrido eso ya lo hice a mano y sigue sin funcionar,

Comment: Te ocurre en todas las imagenes o solo en algunas como el logo? Puedes enseñarnos la query que usaste para reemplazar todos los enlaces?

Comment: ocurre con todas las imagenes. y lo hice a mano todo con el phpadmin del servidor.

Comment: Podrías pasarnos el link de tu página para verificar?

Comment: http://seaagency.net/

Comment: Prueba usando este plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que Wordpress almacena las imágenes en la siguiente ruta:

```
public_html
├── wp-content
│   └── uploads
|          └── 2019
|                └── 01
|                     └── imagen-1-enero-2019.jpg
|                     └── imagen-9-enero-2019.png
|                └── 02
|                └── ...
|          └── 2018
|                └── 01
|                └── 02
|                └── ...
```

Es decir, dentro de `wp-content`, hay un directorio `uploads` y dentro de él Wordpress va organizando las imágenes primero por año, luego por meses y luego dentro de cada mes los archivos que se crearon ese día.

Por tanto, cuando migras un sitio de Wordpress, **salvaguardar la carpeta `wp-content`, incluyendo la sub-carpeta `uploads`que hay dentro de ella es fundamental.

Una vez migrado el sitio, sólo tienes que colocar esa carpeta tal cual en el directorio `wp-content/uploads` de tu nuevo Wordpress y cada post tomará las imágenes que le corresponde.

#### Algunas recomendaciones

- Wordpress tiene una forma muy particular de crear las imágenes, por lo que una sustitución *a mano* de las mismas puede que no funcione bien.
- Si la migración fue debida a un hackeo del sitio, antes de colocar las imágenes, conviene que revises el contenido de `uploads` del sitio antiguo. Hay hackeos que afectan a esa carpeta y muchos programas dañinos pueden disfrazarse como archivos de imagen. En ese caso deberías pasar un antivirus de confianza a esa carpeta y hacer un preview de cada sub-carpeta, que te ayudará a detectar qué archivos no son realmente imágenes.

Aquí te dejo una captura de mi carpeta `uploads`, para que te hagas una idea de cómo Wordpress organiza las imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### EDICIÓN: El código fuente de tu página

En el código fuente de tu página se nota otra anomalía, y es que las imágenes fallidas incluyen una parte de ruta que no sé de donde salen. Veamos esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observa a la derecha en el cuadro verde, la URL se está construyendo así:

```
http://seagency.seagrupo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Confiable.png
```

O sea, a la URL se le está agregando la palabra `seagrupo`, lo cual produce una URL incorrecta, si le quitas esa palabra, la imagen se abre bien:

```
http://seagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Confiable.png
```

Tienes por tanto que investigar si `seagrupo` se agrega por alguna vía, como una regla `.htaccess`, la base de datos o otra ... o si es un problema de tu instalación de Wordpress que no está en la carpeta correcta.

Comment: amigo la migracion se llevo a cabo simplmente por un cambio de dominio y las carpetas estan tal cual como tu lo mencionas, y en la url de base de datos esta la direccion donde se encuentra la imagen y en el servidor si buscas esa direccion alli esta la imagen, el problema es que cuando cargo la imagen en la url le añade el subdominio anterior y por eso no carga la imagen, ejemplo, cuando veo la url de la imagen que no carga es esta:  http://dominioNuevo.dominioAnterior.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/imagen.jpg , le esta colocando el dominio anterior en la url y por eso no la carga.

Comment: @JulianProg en ese caso revisa tu archivo `.htaccess`, puede que allí tengas alguna directiva particular con respecto a las imágenes. En la URL `seaagency.net`, se ve que intenta buscar las imágenes en un directorio llamado `imágenes`, no sé si hiciste alguna redirección allí desde alguna parte ¿?

Comment: donde viste eso?

Comment: @JulianProg en el menú de `Desarrollo`, en la opción `Mostrar código fuente de la página` se puede ver todo el contenido de una página, las URL fallidas y hacia donde apuntan, etc.

Comment: @JulianProg revisa mi respuesta editada. A la URL de las imágenes se le está agregando una palabra `seagrupo` que está produciendo una URL incorrecta para las imágenes.

Comment: si amigo, a eso es que me refiero, el problema es que ya no se que modificar para que eso no suceda, esa imagen Congiable.png la busque en la base de datos en la tabla wp-posts busque esa url y la modifique como debe ser y aun asì sigue igual, alguna otra cosa que deba modificar? eso que dice Seagrupo.com era el dominio anterior.

Comment: @JulianProg tienes que revisar por ejemplo el archivo `.htaccess` que hay dentro de `uploads` o dentro de `wp-content` y también el `.htaccess` de `public_html`, no sea que las imágenes se estén redirigiendo por alguna regla de ese archivo. Ten cuidado al manipula el `.htaccess` cualquier error en él dejaría el sitio fuera de servicio. Otra cosa que deberías decirnos es en qué carpeta se encuentra instalado tu nuevo Wordpress, y verificar qué ruta tiene indicada en la base de datos. O si usas algún plugin de imágenes o algo así

Comment: Viendo que se movie de un subdominio, el `htaccess` posiblemente este bien, ya que tendra de base `/`. Puede que este relacionado con el builder que usa en wordpress "Divi", ya que algunos como "Elementor" guardan las estructuras en sitios raros. El caso de Divi no se como sera.

Comment: lo resolvi editando de nuevo la pagina. pero no deberia de ser asi.

Comment: @JulianProg no sé que decirte. Tu último comentario hace pensar que sería un problema de caché quizá. No sé si tendrás algún plugin para manejar la caché, en cuyo caso deberías limpiar la caché del navegador y resetearla en las opciones del plugin.

Comment: la cache la limpie un millon de veces cada vez que hacia un cambio.

Comment: @JulianProg yo para probar me fui de nuevo a tu sitio y me seguía saliendo erróneo. Le di a limpiar la caché en mis opciones de desarrollador y entonces sí me mostró la imagen `Confiable` (y las otras imágenes que antes eran erróneas) correctamente. Debe haber algo relativo a la caché entonces.

Comment: te las mostro porque edite la pagina wordpress con un editor y volvi a colocar las imagenes nuevamente, pero no creo que sea algo referente a la cache, es algo referente a wordpress que aun no se que sera. Es como que si no se hubiese seteado la url de las imagenes luego de cambiar el dominio.

Comment: @JulianProg no, cuando me dijiste que funcionaba me fui a la página y la actualicé varias veces y me seguía mostrando error. Limpié la caché y entonces funcionó. Por tanto el contenido de tu página se está cacheando en alguna parte. A veces el mismo hosting agrega reglas de caché en el `.htaccess`, (el mío empezó a hacerlo hace ya un tiempo) lo cual está bien, pero fastidia cuando estás probando algo.